# JSON - How to iterate nested dictionaries in a list

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following JSON data in a file:

```
{
    "Generic": {
        "main": [{
            "one": "Main 1",
            "two": "Main 2"
        }],
        "rows": [
            {
                "row1": "This is row 1-1",
                "row2": "This is row 2-1",
                "row3": "This is row 3-1"
            },
            {
                "row1": "This is row 1-2",
                "row2": "This is row 2-2",
                "row3": "This is row 3-2"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I can access the values like so:

```
import json

with open(r'C:\generic.json') as json_data:
json_data = json.load(json_data)

for x in sorted(json_data):
  print (x)
  print ('main:')
  print (json_data[x]['main'][0]['one'])
  print (json_data[x]['main'][0]['two'])
  print ('rows:')
  print (json_data[x]['rows'][0]['row1'])
  print (json_data[x]['rows'][0]['row2'])
  print (json_data[x]['rows'][0]['row3'])
  print ('')

  for y in json_data[x]:
    print (json_data[x]['rows'][0]['row1'])
```

This returns:

[image: output]

My problem is how do I iterate all of the nested dictionaries in `"rows"` - in this case there are 2. You can see my sad attempt at `for y in json_data[x]:`

Note: I access the `"rows"` data in the the 1st loop to show that it is accessible - but I need to figure out how to access those rows in a 2nd loop.

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

EDIT:

I am closer with the following - I am SO close but not sure what little piece I am missing:

```
for x in sorted(json_data):
    print (x)
    print ('main:')
    print (json_data[x]['main'][0]['one'])
    print (json_data[x]['main'][0]['two'])
    print ('rows:')
    print (json_data[x]['rows'][0]['row1'])
    print (json_data[x]['rows'][0]['row2'])
    print (json_data[x]['rows'][0]['row3'])
    print ('')

    for r in json_data[x]['rows']:
        print (json_data[x]['rows'][0]['row1'])
        print (json_data[x]['rows'][0]['row2'])
        print (json_data[x]['rows'][0]['row3'])
```

The `for r in json_data[x]['rows']:` recognizes the correct number of `"rows"` - whether 2 or 5o - but just returns the values from the 1st dictionary over and over :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looping over `['rows']`, you simply need to use the `r` variable. Use this:

```
for r in json_data['Generic']['rows']:
    print(r['row1'])
    print(r['row2'])
    print(r['row3'])
```

Output:

```
This is row 1-1
This is row 2-1
This is row 3-1
This is row 1-2
This is row 2-2
This is row 3-2
```

The reason you were getting only the first dictionary is - you were using `json_data[x]['rows'][0]` inside the loop. This `[0]` will always give you the first item (dictionary) in the `'rows'` list.

Comment: I went on a short walk to clear my head and I was like duh! the r - but I tried it when I got home and was using it wrong - you sir are a "steel-eyed missile man" Thank you :)